# Grid cell does not stretch if there is more content

Tags: angular, angular-material, responsive, grid-layout

I'm new in Angular material.

I tried to make a grid layout,
But when I have more content on the card, the cell does not expand.

He is hiding underneath.
And I also can't get grid layout responsive.
How can I change colspan i rowspan depending on screen resolution?

Here you can see what I did:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmhut9

Answer (score 0):

In the mat-grid you put rowHeight="250px" so you put a force on it to not go larger so you can either remove it and your on css which is a min-height:250px; and it will keep it auto size or if you need it forced to be 250px height without being auto expanded, then you need to edit your css here:

```
.dashboard-card{
   position:absolute;
   top:15px;
   bottom:15px;
   left:15px;
   right:15px;
   overflow:auto; //this the the line to be added
}
```